# What is the difference between "consuming a rest api" and "writing a rest client"?

Tags: ruby, api, rest

As stated. I am using ruby to perform my task. I am to create a webpage that takes in user input and makes calls using the API back and forth. However, I am yet to understand how to deal with these APIs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *consume* the API you are essentially making use of the service. So you are sending data and are, potentially, getting something back.

When you write a rest client, you are essentially writing an entity which will consume the API. The rest client could also provide some functionality to ease the consumption of the API, for instance if your API requires a time stamp, the rest client could automatically provide the current time stamp, or else provide the user with a nice UI control to do so easily, rather than type something like this: `22-10-2002 12:10:11 GMT`.

The client itself can take different forms. It could be a simple page on a web page, or a more complex desktop or mobile application.

Comment: "rest client" could also refer to a library, e.g. https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client